# Creating graph vertices from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, networkx

I have a numpy array full of values that I would like to create vertices from for every point in the array. I am using networkx as my graphing support method(documentation here:
http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/ )

I would like to treat each element within the array as a pixel location and create a vertex instance at each location. This is easy using a simple for loop:

```
new=np.arange(16)
gnew=nx.Graph()
for x in new:
    if new[x]>0:
        gnew.add_node(x)
h=gnew.number_of_nodes()
print h
```

And as expected, 15 nodes will be printed. However, this becomes more tricky when you have identical values. For example:

```
new=np.ones(16)
gnew=nx.Graph()
for x in new:
    if new[x]>0:
        gnew.add_node(x)
h=gnew.number_of_nodes()
print h
```

Now, because all values are identical-(1), only one node will be added to the graph. Is there a way to circumnavigate this?

Comment: Just a quick comment - `G.order()` is the same as `G.number_of_nodes()`, but shorter...

Comment: The link is broken, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetworkX requires that each node have a unique name. You could generate unique names and then set the elements of your array to be **attributes** of the nodes, e.g.

```
new = np.ones(16);
othernew = np.arange(16)

G = nx.Graph()
for i in range(len(othernew)):
   if new[i]>0:
      G.add_node(othernew[i])
      G.node[othernew[i]]['pos'] = new[i] #This gives the node a position attribute with value new[i]

h = G.order()
print(h)

>>16
```

Comment: Thanks @jgloves, I should've checked back here sooner as I just arrived at the same conclusion you did and have written my code in the same way.

Comment: You're quite welcome. I'm glad you were able to solve it!

Comment: What if your `new` array is instead a 2D numpy array? So basically, what if you want to turn a raster image into a graph where the attribute of the node is the value in the array?